# How to get fixed/consistent exposure for a series of shots using remote trigger?

Tags: canon, timelapse, manual-mode

A friend recently asked for my help to take a series of photos that he could use to create a time lapse effect. For context, it was of him preparing a cocktail for a talk he was giving. Couple of shots below,

https://www.flickr.com/photos/stephenmelrose/24585246491/in/dateposted-public/
https://www.flickr.com/photos/stephenmelrose/24051910643/in/dateposted-public/

For the most part, we got exactly what we needed, but during processing in Lightroom I noticed some **subtle differences in exposure** between some of the shots. I managed to correct this, but I figured there's probably a way to eliminate this problem during the shoot altogether?

The setup was as follows,

- Canon 100D in manual mode. ƒ/4.0, 24mm, 1/125, 1600.
- Camera was mounted on a tripod.
- Flash gun pointing into the ceiling for ambient light.
- Used BBF in "AE lock/AF" mode.
- Driver set to "Self-timer/remote" and I used the IR remote.
- AF was "AI Focus AF".
- Metering was "Evaluative".
- White balance was "Auto".

(Can happily provide any other details, but most/all other settings were just the default)

From my basic amateur knowledge, I guess the camera was adjusting something between each shot? Was there a setting I missed that I needed to be able to lock things properly to get fully consistent shots? The subject was moving about, but in position. I guess that could have had an effect on the light and white balance?

Apologies if the detail is vague. Not really sure what the problem was, hence having trouble trying to find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Flash gun pointed to the ceiling gives you diffused flash, not ambient light. *Ambient* light in a photo or video context means light that you don't add to the scene, like sunlight, room lighting, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you write I have three suggestions to make more consistent photos

1. Set white balance to some value, this will help you to mitigate
   colour casts
2. Set focus to manual and focus to particular point (also get in
   consideration to change aperture to have appropriate depth of field)
3. Set flash to manual to some value, which is fine for your purpose

P.S. As you set camera in manual mode you do not need AE lock. Nor you need AF lock when set to manual focus